# Authenticate two parameters in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I built a simple api endpoint using Django Rest Framework where, in order to see the endpoint's data, the user needs to input a public key and a secret key. Here is what i did:

```
class CustomAuthentication(authentication.BaseAuthentication):

    def authenticate(self, request):

        # Get the username and password
        public = request.data.get('public', None)
        secret = request.data.get('secret', None)

        if not public or not secret:
            raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed(_('No credentials provided.'))

        credentials = {
            get_user_model().USERNAME_FIELD: public,
            'secret': secret
        }

        user = authenticate(**credentials)

        if user is None:
            raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed(_('Invalid username/password.'))

        if not user.is_active:
            raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed(_('User inactive or deleted.'))


        return (user, None)  # authentication successful

class My_View(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    authentication_classes = (CustomAuthentication,)
    ...
```

Now, i'm trying to access the endpoint like that: localhost/api/endpoint/?public=TEST&secret=TEST but every time i get  `"No credentials provided."`. What do i need to do in order to be authenticated here? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/requests/#data)

> `request.data` returns the parsed content of the request body.

You are passing data as [query params](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/requests/#query_params) in URL. Change to

```
public = request.query_params.get('public', None)
secret = request.query_params.get('secret', None)
```

However, data passed using query params are visible [meaning the secret key won't be kept secret] and this sort of authentication isn't safe.

Refer to https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#authentication for more details.

Comment: Thank you a lot! Unfortunately this is as much as i can do in terms of security, it's a simple endpoint where you can only view data, no POST, so security is not a big deal here